# EasyAdmin form select box EntityType not populating

Tags: symfony, easyadmin

I'm trying to populate select box with OneToMany relationship in EasyAdmin form. However, the **status** field is not being populated with the TaskStatus records from my database, while the assignedUsers does. Here's my FormType:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add(
            'assignedUsers',
            EntityType::class, [
                'class' => User::class,
                'label' => 'Choose assigned users',
                'multiple' => true,
                'required' => true
            ]
        )
        ->add('status',
            EntityType::class, [
                'class' => TaskStatus::class,
                'label' => 'Task status',
                'choice_label' => 'title',
                'choice_value' => 'id',
                'multiple' => false,
                'required' => true
        ]);
}
```

Here's my Task and TaskStatus entity relations:

**TASK:**

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Components\Task\Entity\TaskStatus", inversedBy="task")
 */
protected $status;
```

**TASK STATUS:**

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="App\Components\Task\Entity\Task", mappedBy="status")
 **/
private $task;
```

Comment: What do you mean with populate?

Comment: The select box stays empty, I have 3 TaskStatus records in my database.

Comment: empty in 3 empty lines or empty in no entries? (check in output html)

Comment: Empty in no entries - <select id="task_status" name="task[status]" class="form-control"></select>

Comment: that is indeed really weird. have you tried clearing the cache? have you excluded all non-obvious mistakes, like different database is used than the one you're looking at, wrong table looked at. Have you checked in code to retrieve the TaskStatus via EntityManager? maybe form theming that removes the options for that particular field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that I used wrong repository for my TaskStatus entity:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Components\Task\Repository\TaskRepository")
 */
```

Right one is:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Components\Task\Repository\TaskStatusRepository")
 */
```